# How to set up declarative_authorization for every user

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, declarative-authorization

I have these two models:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
end
```

and this set up of `declarative_authorization` for a role:

```
  role :reg_ser do
     has_permission_on :photos, :to => [:show] do
       if_attribute :user_id => is { user.id }
     end
  end
```

and I want to allow display to user the image that he upload - only his images. I mean, for example:

```
user_id | photo
      1 | 1
      1 | 2
      1 | 3
      2 | 4
```

And when the user set the url `/photos/1`, so this image will be displayed only for `user_id` with the number `1`, when the `user_id=2` will display this address, he don't see the image...

Is possible something like this to do?

Comment: Do you mean you are using "declarative_authorization"???  If so you've pretty much hit the nail on the head already, assuming you have an appropriately named controller with a "filter_resource_access" directive.

Comment: I need already some sleep. Thanks for kick me up!

Comment: you can use cancan and devise to make things a lot more easier for you

Answer (score 0):

You need to put something like

```
filter_access_to [:index, :new, :create]
filter_access_to [:show, :edit, :update], :attribute_check => true
```

in your controller and something like

```
role :reg_ser do
  has_permission_on :photos, :to => [:index, :new, :create]
  has_permission_on :photos, :to => [:show, :edit: update] do
    if_attribute :user_id => is { user.id }
  end
end
```

into `authorization_rules.rb`. So everything works properly it is important that you include the `:attribute_check` in the controller for every action where you want to check on attributes.
I left `:index` without it, as it is quite easy to just show current user's things by adding

```
def begin_of_association_chain
  current_user
end
```

or similar to the controller (this would be causing InheritedResources to have `current_user.pictures` as the collection).

You may also be interested in reading http://asciicasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization